# Network changes behavior of Command Prompt

Tags: windows-7, networking

I am working on a computer that is connected to our company network and try to execute a script that pulls a build from our svn. Whenever I supply the script with username and password and execute it, I get a Windows Security login box. When I supply the same credentials it fails and the script tells me I am not authenticated.

Now the kicker: When I instead connect the computer through my cell phone mobile hotspot and execute the very same command, it runs fine and pulls the build.

What could cause this behavior? I doubt it is the UAC since I can run it on my mobile network. Also, I am fine to connect to the resource via the browser on the company network, thus it is not blocked. I am pulling out the few remaining hairs I have over this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVN uses a different IP port than web browsing.  I would think that your company's proxy and/or firewall are blocking the direct SVN access port (3690), while your browser uses port 80.

Your mobile would have no such restriction on it (unless you specifically put it there).

Can you verify that your script is trying to connect via port 3690, rather than port 80?

Comment: How would i find out which port is being used? WireShark?

Comment: Yeah, that'd be one way.  Or whatever tool you use for your SVN sync (svn.exe?) should be able to tell you what port it uses.

Comment: Its a custom executable, which I have the source code of. I believe it goes over port 80. None of the code suggests an SVN specific port/connection. I builds a path and tries to download a zip file directly. The authentication part breaks (through the API).

Comment: I just checked and it is using SSL (443) as the port. This port is open even when on company network...

Comment: When you say "open even when on company network", it sounds like you're talking about the Windows firewall on your PC, not the corporate firewall.  If so, can you find out about your corporate firewall?  Also, is there any chance the authentication prompt is coming from your company's proxy, rather than from SVN?  You could use Wireshark to determine who, exactly, is not liking your authentication.  And does the custom executable work when you run it directly, rather than through a script?

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. 1) The authentication prompt is coming from the company's proxy. 2) The executable asks for the credentials even when run directly. I don't think it has to do with the Windows firewall, as you already pointed out, since it works on the same computer when disconnected to the corporate network.

Comment: Well then, now you just need to work with your developer and your IT department and get the custom executable to authenticate properly to your proxy.  :-)